# custom audio player using responsive html5

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I asking about many points:

1. can I create my custom responsive audio player using html5 only without JQuery?
2. Is audio player which created with jquery can play on mobile or tab?
3. any Examples to guide me to built in my custom audio player?
4. shall I use HTML5 control

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can, but using plain JavaScript.
2. It depends on mobile browser, mostly yes, can play on mobile.
3. Audio player without jquery [HTML5 Javascript cusotm player](http://www.alexkatz.me/html5-audio/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/)
4. To be stable on all devices, yes, you should.

For any other question, just ask in comment please.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried to create my own audio player that will play on any mobile or tablet , So belongs to your answer, I can Do this by create my own player using only HTML5 and pure JavaScript without any plugins , is it correct?

Comment: yes, you can create your own player using only HTML5 and pure JavaScript and style it with CSS. You can build some really beautiful players with JS.